# assign variables automatically when the loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

p_dil_1, p_dil_2, p_dil_3, p_dil_4 ..... are variables I have already made.

```
tg1 = p_dil_1
tg2 = p_dil_2
n_dil = 0

while True : 
    n_dil += 1
    # some movement here
    
    if n_dil == 10 :
        break
    if n_dil <= 10 : 
        tg1 = p_dil_2
        tg2 = p_dil_3
        continue
```

The original purpose is

For the first loop, tg1=p_dil_1, tg2=p_dil_2

For the second loop, tg1=p_dil_2, tg2=p_dil_3

...

For the tenth loop, tg1=p_dil_10, tg2=p_dil_11

and end the loop

How can I make the loop simple?

Comment: I only see one loop.

Comment: Use a list instead of a bunch of "p_dil..." variables.

Comment: to make a list, do I have to assign by my hand like loop=[p_dil_1, p_dil_2,,,,, p_dil_10] ????

Comment: Instead of assigning from the variables to that list, make the list *directly* using whatever calculation you had for the initial values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make things a bit simpler and cleaner.

```
var listOfValues = [p_dil_1, p_dil_2, ..., p_dil_11] // etc.
for n_dil = 0; n_dil <= 10; n_dil += 1 {
    // Some Movement
    tg1 = listOfValues[n_dil]; tg2= listOfValues[n_dil + 1];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign variables dynamically.  Use a list and use a variable to reference the position in the list.

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
index = 0
while index < 5:
  var1 = list[index]
  var2 = list[index + 1]
  # use var, var2
  index = index + 1
```

Comment: Mark the answer correct if so.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to use dictionaries. Please also check your logic as when `n_dil = 10` the last, if statement will never be executed as the loop, breaks first.

```py
p_dil_dict = {1: "foo", ..., 2: "bar"}
tg1 = p_dil_dict["1"]
tg2 = p_dil_dict["2"]

for n_dil in range(1, 10): # n_dil = 1, 2..., 8, 9
    # do something

    tg1 = p_dil_dict[n_dil]
    tg2 = p_dil_dict[n_dil]
```

Notice how a for loop can be started at 1 if necessary (although I'd recommend starting at 0). Also the for loop means you don't need to break a while loop or set and increment `n_dil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your p_dil_1, p_dil_2... etc in a list, lets say - `p_dil[]`. You can initialize `tg1` and `tg2` with `p_dil[0]` and `p_dil[1]`. Then start your loop with `n_dil = 2` and note that the variable  `tg1` takes the value of `tg2` from the previous iteration.

```
p_dil = [p_dil_1, p_dil_2, ....]
tg1 = p_dil[0]
tg2 = p_dil[1]
n_dil = 2
while n_dil <= 10:
    tg1 = tg2
    tg2 = p_dil[n_dil]
    n_dil += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using for loop?

```py
tgs = [p_dil_3, p_dil_4, ..., p_dil_11]
tg1, tg2 = p_dil_1, p_dil_2

for new_dil in range(tgs):
    # some movement....
    tg1 = tg2
    tg2 = new_dil
```